# How to find if a column has DATE in it using python?

Tags: python, regex, dataframe, datetime, match

I am new to DateTime, regex. So, I have a dataset where a column has dates in it`(It can have any format like shown below)`. I would like to know if the column has a date in it or not. I used regex though getting the wrong output. How to deal with it?

My code:

```
df = 
   name  date
0  a     2020-01-23
1  c     01-24-2020
2  d     24-01-2020
3  e     2020/01/23
4  f     01/23/2020
5  r     23/01/2020
6  t     20200123
7  I     01232020
8  j     23012020

for i in df.date:
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if re.search("^([1-9] |1[0-9]| 2[0-9]|3[0-1])(.|-)([1-9] |1[0-2])(.|-|)20[0-9][0-9]$",str(df[i])) != None:
          print('Yes')
        else:
          print('No')
```

Gives an error:

```
KeyError: '2020-01-23'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
```

Where am I going wrong? Is it the format of regex?

Comment: `df` doesn't have the keyword `2020-01-23` as mentioned in your error. Use `i` instead of `df[i]` inside the loop directly.

Comment: You can create a new column of standard date by applying pd.to_datetime to date column and check in that column if date is available or are there null values. I think there is no need of regex.

Comment: Furthermore, according to https://regex101.com/r/kKsdCb/1 your regex doesn't match any string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That's a simple code and it is working fine with all Date types. Thanks aloot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do the following:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if re.search("your regex here", row.date) != None:
        print('Yes')
    else:
        print('No')
```

Since you are iterating over the rows already, you can access the date field very easily with the dot notation `row.date`.

As a side note, you could compile your regex before the for loop, it should boost the speed a bit. Also, once you get the logic in place, consider using `df.apply()` instead of iterating over each row.

Comment: `your regex here` won't work. `^([1-9] |1[0-9]| 2[0-9]|3[0-1])(.|-)([1-9] |1[0-2])(.|-|)20[0-9][0-9]$` is a buggy expression.

Answer (score 0):

It's a key error you are essentially doing

```
        if re.search("^([1-9] |1[0-9]| 2[0-9]|3[0-1])(.|-)([1-9] |1[0-2])(.|-|)20[0-9][0-9]$",str(df['2020-01-23'])) != None:
```

I think you mean to be doing

```
        if re.search("^([1-9] |1[0-9]| 2[0-9]|3[0-1])(.|-)([1-9] |1[0-2])(.|-|)20[0-9][0-9]$",str(df[index])) != None:
```

which then becomes:

```
        if re.search("^([1-9] |1[0-9]| 2[0-9]|3[0-1])(.|-)([1-9] |1[0-2])(.|-|)20[0-9][0-9]$",str(df[0])) != None:
```

Comment: If he iterates `i` for all dates, he can directly use `i` inside the loop. No need for df lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think you can directly convert all into date formats using below code.

`$` df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).apply(lambda x: x.date() if x else '')

Above code will fill date column with real dates and will ignore those have empty strings.

Comment: This throws *`dateutil.parser._parser.ParserError: month must be in 1..12: 01232020`*

Answer (score -1):

Hi check below code it will convert valid string into date otherwise it will fill invalid strings with Nan.

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
import numpy as np

def check_date(x, fuzzy=False):
    try: 
        parse(str(x), fuzzy=fuzzy)
        return x
    except ValueError:
        return np.na

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].apply(lambda x: check_date(x)))
```

Hope it will work for you!!